# How to do request-response pattern with WebSockets

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, socket.io, request-response

I am using Socket.io, and I am wondering if there is a good way to use the request / response pattern. Is the best way to do this to use a UUID for each request, and then only handle data from a response that contains that UUID? That's perhaps not the most scalable way to do things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Socket.io has the option to send an acknowledgement back. It's possible to include data into this callback ([see here](https://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements))). I use it as follows:

**Server** side:

```
socket.on('event', function(msg, callback) {
 console.log('event received: '+msg);
 callback("Here could be your data");
});
```

**Client** side:

```
socket.emit('event', "my data", function(callbackData){
    console.log('Callback data:', callbackData);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks, in this case, I am actually looking to get confirmation that the server received the message from the client, not the other way around.